# (Unity) Как записывать и инвертировать все звуки, которые происходили перед инверсией?

Tags: unity3d, аудио, время

Пишу класс, который будет по желанию игрока инвертировать всё, что происходит в игре.(позиции, повороты, физику и т.п.) Много посмотрел скриптов, но так и не увидел такого, который мог в какой-то лист, массив записывать все звуки из AudioSource, а потом с какого-то момента воспроизводить назад. Важно понимать, что после отмотки он должен записывать с того момента, где закончилась наша инверсия. То есть у нас есть 3 аудио трека. 1 -> 2 -> 3 Мы инвертируем. 3 -> 2. Останавливаемся, а потом идёт 2 -> 3 и т.п. Увидел только такой вариант, но он мне не подходит, т.к. он лишь меняет питч для отдельного трека + нельзя воспроизвести с конца.

```
audioSource.pitch = -audioSource.pitch
```

Comment: так питч это тональность, а не реверс. А ты ищешь реверс аудио. А вообще вопрос очень плохо сформулирован. Такое чувство что в него напиано 3-4 вопроса. Очень совую сузить тематику вопроса и конкретизировать что именно не выходит

Comment: @Andrew если совсем просто, то просто расскажите, как мне записать информацию по каждому воспроизведённому клипу из source и затем воспроизвести задом наперёд.

Comment: сделать реверс аудиозаписей и проиграть в обратном порядке относительно нормальной последовательности?

Comment: @Andrew можете привести пример кода, не совсем понимаю о чём вы. Смогу принять ответ.

Comment: весьма странно, но гугл и вправду говорит что реверс аудио в юнити делается через питч. Но вообще словом "питч" в аудиоредакторах обозначают ИЗМЕНЕНИЕ ТОНАЛЬНОСТИ ЗВУКА(что бы ты понимал что это - вот пример - https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7b-sj7x8Qzo ) и на скорость он влиять не должен. То ли юнитисты намудровали и неправильно назвали переменную, то ли советчики из интернета что-то намудрили и ты у них перенял это(мое гугление реверса так же привело к тому что люди советуют менять питч).

Comment: По логике питч не должен влиять на скорость воспроизведение и не должен делать реверс аудио даже в теории. Как именно его делать коректно я не в курсе. Но точно не через общепринятое понятие питча.

Comment: @Andrew а мне то что делать) В интернете ничего нет, есть идеи?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Гугление показало что юнитисты и вправду намудрили с наименованием переменной и назвали ее совсем не тем именем, которым она должна называться.

> Unity can only change the speed of an AudioSource. It calls this
> parameter "Pitch". However, changing it will always change both pitch
> and tempo, since this is just a matterl of changin the playback
> sampling rate and can be done in realtime at almost no cost and with
> (almost) no sound distortion.
> https://answers.unity.com/questions/25139/how-i-can-change-the-speed-of-a-song-or-sound.html

Если коротко и по-русски: переменная `Pitch` у них должна быть названа `PlaybackSpeed` или `Tempo` т.к. она не отвечает за общепринятый термин "Pitch" (тональность звука), а отвечает за скорость воспроизведения.

Так что ты должен сделать для реверса :

```
audioSource.pitch = -1;
```

держа в голове что это не  pitch, а tempo.

но при этом желательно что бы сам аудиоклип был импортирован как wav потому как пережатое аудио прийдется ресемплировать, а на ходу это занимает достаточно много ресурсов.

Или же ты должен найти алгоритм как это можно делать без сильных затрат ресурсов. Например можно подсмотреть в открытом коде VLC реализацию.

Или же можно поискать готовые библиотеки обработки звука которые можно подключать к юнити.
Вероятнее всего есть импортированная в юнити NAudio - поищи в эту сторону.

---

Что до того как записать все звуки и последовательности звуков и музыки - это так же достаточно дорогое по ресурсам удовольствие.
Лучше будет если сохранять условную позицию на таймлайне какой звук когда начал проигрываться, а потом включать обратное воспроизведение в обратном порядке.

Comment: Я то знаю, как это работает. Просто проблема в том, что мне нужно записывать 15+ звуков, а писать для этого костыли не хотелось бы.

Comment: в коде VLC (он опенсоурсный) можно попробовать найти решение как они оптимизировали реверс на ходу. Или же можно поискать готовые библиотеки обработки звука которые можно подключать к юнити. Вероятнее всего есть импортированная в юнити NAudio - поищи в эту сторону.